# how to use Apache Commons Math Optimization in Jython?

Tags: optimization, jython, apache-commons-math

I want to transfer Matlab code to Jython version, and find that the fminsearch in Matlab might be replaced by Apache-Common-Math-Optimization.
I'm coding on the Mango Medical Image script manager, which uses Jython 2.5.3  as coding language. And the Math version is 3.6.1. 
Here is my code:

```html
def f(x,y):
 return x^2+y^2

sys.path.append('/home/shujian/APPs/Mango/lib/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar')
sys.add_package('org.apache.commons.math3.analysis')
from org.apache.commons.math3.analysis import MultivariateFunction
sys.add_package('org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv')
from org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv import NelderMeadSimplex,SimplexOptimizer
sys.add_package('org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar')
from org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar import ObjectiveFunction
sys.add_package('org.apache.commons.math3.optim')
from org.apache.commons.math3.optim import MaxEval,InitialGuess
sys.add_package('org.apache.commons.math3.optimization')
from org.apache.commons.math3.optimization import GoalType

initialSolution=[2.0,2.0]
simplex=NelderMeadSimplex([2.0,2.0])
opt=SimplexOptimizer(2**(-6), 2**(-10))
solution=opt.optimize(MaxEval(300),ObjectiveFunction(f),simplex,GoalType.MINIMIZE,InitialGuess([2.0,2.0]))

skewParameters2 = solution.getPointRef()
print skewParameters2;
```

And I got the error below：

```html
TypeError: optimize(): 1st arg can't be coerced to
```

I'm quite confused about how to use the optimization in Jython and the examples are all Java version.

Answer (score 0):

I've given up this plan and find another method to perform the fminsearch in Jython. Below is the Jython version code:

```html
import sys
sys.path.append('.../jnumeric-2.5.1_ra0.1.jar')   #add the jnumeric path
import Numeric as np
def nelder_mead(f, x_start,
                step=0.1, no_improve_thr=10e-6,
                no_improv_break=10, max_iter=0,
                alpha=1., gamma=2., rho=-0.5, sigma=0.5):
    '''
        @param f (function): function to optimize, must return a scalar score
            and operate over a numpy array of the same dimensions as x_start
        @param x_start (float list): initial position
        @param step (float): look-around radius in initial step
        @no_improv_thr,  no_improv_break (float, int): break after no_improv_break iterations with
            an improvement lower than no_improv_thr
        @max_iter (int): always break after this number of iterations.
            Set it to 0 to loop indefinitely.
        @alpha, gamma, rho, sigma (floats): parameters of the algorithm
            (see Wikipedia page for reference)

        return: tuple (best parameter array, best score)
    '''

    # init
    dim = len(x_start)
    prev_best = f(x_start)
    no_improv = 0
    res = [[np.array(x_start), prev_best]]

    for i in range(dim):
        x=np.array(x_start)
        x[i]=x[i]+step
        score = f(x)
        res.append([x, score])

    # simplex iter
    iters = 0
    while 1:
        # order
        res.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
        best = res[0][1]

        # break after max_iter
        if max_iter and iters >= max_iter:
            return res[0]
        iters += 1

        # break after no_improv_break iterations with no improvement
        print '...best so far:', best

        if best < prev_best - no_improve_thr:
            no_improv = 0
            prev_best = best
        else:
            no_improv += 1

        if no_improv >= no_improv_break:
            return res[0]

        # centroid
        x0 = [0.] * dim
        for tup in res[:-1]:
            for i, c in enumerate(tup[0]):
                x0[i] += c / (len(res)-1)

        # reflection
        xr = x0 + alpha*(x0 - res[-1][0])
        rscore = f(xr)
        if res[0][1] <= rscore < res[-2][1]:
            del res[-1]
            res.append([xr, rscore])
            continue

        # expansion
        if rscore < res[0][1]:
            xe = x0 + gamma*(x0 - res[-1][0])
            escore = f(xe)
            if escore < rscore:
                del res[-1]
                res.append([xe, escore])
                continue
            else:
                del res[-1]
                res.append([xr, rscore])
                continue

        # contraction
        xc = x0 + rho*(x0 - res[-1][0])
        cscore = f(xc)
        if cscore < res[-1][1]:
            del res[-1]
            res.append([xc, cscore])
            continue

        # reduction
        x1 = res[0][0]
        nres = []
        for tup in res:
            redx = x1 + sigma*(tup[0] - x1)
            score = f(redx)
            nres.append([redx, score])
        res = nres
```

And the test example is as below:

```html
def f(x):
        return x[0]**2+x[1]**2+x[2]**2

print nelder_mead(f,[3.4,2.3,2.2])
```

Actually, the original version is for python, and the link below is the source:
https://github.com/fchollet/nelder-mead